# Unable to create Sales Order from JCO

Tags: sap-erp, bapi, jco

I am using the below code to call `BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2` to create the Sales Order. SAP ERP software is generating a SO number and sending as a response but when I check with `va03` for the SO number which I have received, sales order is not created .

If I do manually using `va01` with the same data I can create the sales order successfully. Please need help on this .

```
public static void createSalesOrder() {
    try {
        JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("ABAP_AS_WITH_POOL");
        JCoFunction functionCreateOrder = destination.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2");
        //this is the bapi 
        JCoFunction functionTransComit = destination.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");

        JCoStructure orderHeaderIn = functionCreateOrder.getImportParameterList().getStructure("ORDER_HEADER_IN");
        orderHeaderIn.setValue("SALES_ORG", "2000");//sales organisation
        orderHeaderIn.setValue("DISTR_CHAN", "20");//distribution channel
        orderHeaderIn.setValue("DIVISION", "20");// sales division 
        orderHeaderIn.setValue("DOC_TYPE", "ZAR");// document type 
        orderHeaderIn.setValue("PURCH_NO_C", "TEST123");
        

        JCoTable orderPartners = functionCreateOrder.getTableParameterList().getTable("ORDER_PARTNERS");
        // WE,AG,SP,PH
        // AG Sold to Party
        // WE Ship to Partyx
        orderPartners.appendRow();
        orderPartners.setValue("PARTN_ROLE", "AG");//partner role ag is sold to party 
        orderPartners.setValue("PARTN_NUMB", "0000000035");// partner number 
        orderPartners.appendRow();
        orderPartners.setValue("PARTN_ROLE", "WE");//we is ship tp party 
        orderPartners.setValue("PARTN_NUMB", "0000000035");// partner number 
        System.out.println(orderPartners);

        JCoTable orderItemsIn = functionCreateOrder.getTableParameterList().getTable("ORDER_ITEMS_IN");
        orderItemsIn.appendRow();
        orderItemsIn.setValue("MATERIAL", "PEN_ARN");// material 
        System.out.println(orderItemsIn);

        JCoTable orderSchedulesIn = functionCreateOrder.getTableParameterList().getTable("ORDER_SCHEDULES_IN");
        orderSchedulesIn.appendRow();
        orderSchedulesIn.setValue("REQ_QTY", "10");// required quantity 
        System.out.println(orderSchedulesIn);

        functionCreateOrder.execute(destination);
        

        // System.out.println(functionCreateOrder);
        JCoTable returnTable = functionCreateOrder.getTableParameterList().getTable("RETURN");
        System.out.println(returnTable);
        System.out.println(returnTable.getString("MESSAGE"));
        System.out.println("sales order number is : "
                + functionCreateOrder.getExportParameterList().getValue("SALESDOCUMENT"));
        functionTransComit.execute(destination);

    } catch (JCoException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Creating sales order ends");
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while creating sales order using JCO with BAPI\_SALESORDER\_CREATEFROMDAT2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133170/error-while-creating-sales-order-using-jco-with-bapi-salesorder-createfromdat2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your JCo version, but at least with **JCo 3** you need to execute your call to `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` within the same context as your function call to `BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2`. Currently both calls are executed in individual contexts, so the second call to `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` doesn't really commit anything. You have to create a context first:

```
JCoContext.begin(destination);

// execute both function calls to 
// BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2 and
// BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT

JCoContext.end(destination);
```